# Nagios JMX Plugin check_jmx command not found

Tags: centos, jmx, nagios, icinga, nagiosxi

I am setting up the monitoring Kafka with Icinga2 as specified [here](http://neeleshgurjar.co.in/techidnyan/monitoring-kafka-storm-zookeeper-with-icinga2-2/). I am using Centos7 and following the steps mentioned below

Step 1: Downloaded Check_JMX plugin by issuing the command

```
wget -c http://snippets.syabru.ch/nagios-jmx-plugin/download/nagios-jmx-plugin.zip
```

Step 2: Extracted downloaded archive and copied `check_jmx` and `check_jmx.jar` to `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/` folder

Step 3: Verifying the Installation by issuing the command

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_jmx –help
```

and getting the following error:

```
Error:
-bash: ./check_jmx: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by installing and using dos2unix check_jmx